# Calculating the growth rate in panda dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Considering a dataframe like the one below:

```
x =[[  1.     ,   9.61076],
       [  2.     ,   9.61076],
       [  3.     ,  14.41615],
       [  4.     ,  33.63767],
       [  5.     ,  57.66458],
       [  6.     ,  62.46997],
       [  7.     ,  72.08073],
       [  8.     , 172.99375]]

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df = df.set_index(0)
df.head()
```

how can I create a third column that represents the growth rate between a row and its predecessor? In other words, what was the growth or fall from line 2 to line 1, from line 3 to 2, and so on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check with `pct_change`

```
df['pdt_chg']=df[1].pct_change()
df
             1   pdt_chg
0                       
1.0    9.61076       NaN
2.0    9.61076  0.000000
3.0   14.41615  0.500001
4.0   33.63767  1.333332
5.0   57.66458  0.714286
6.0   62.46997  0.083333
7.0   72.08073  0.153846
8.0  172.99375  1.400000
```

Comment: Won't be accurate if negative values are present: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.2/pandas/core/generic.py#L10366

Better would be `df["gr"] = (df["a"] - df["a"].shift()) / abs(df["a"].shift())`